# How to set multiple aliases in vite react?

Tags: reactjs, alias, vite, vite-reactjs

Vite by default does not support src alias like

> `import counterReducer from "@src/pages/counter/counter.slice";`

Every time you will have to pass the full relative path like this

> `import counterReducer from "../../src/pages/counter/counter.slice";`

Is there any way we can shorten these relative paths?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, vite doesn't come with the default configuration of aliases, but you can define your own aliases.

Step: 1
Open "vite.config.js" and add your aliases.
[image: vite.config.js]

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import path from "path";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/"),
      components: `${path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/components/")}`,
      public: `${path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/")}`,
      pages: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/pages"),
      types: `${path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/@types")}`,
    },
  },
});
```

Step 2:
Open tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json and append this code under compiler options. [image: tsconfig.json]

```js
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["./src/*", "./dist/*", ""],
  "pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
  "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
  "types/*": ["src/@types/*"],
  "public/*": ["public/*"]
}
```

Comment: Okay, that initially solved my problem, but now when I import my component, the import looks like this:

`import Container from '../Container'`

but i wanted something like

`import Container from '@components/Container'`

Comment: Your import should look like this "import Container from "Container", if this is not the case, there might be some configuration issue.

Comment: it works for me in one dir and doesn't work in other dir. Damn, I don't know why

Comment: @JonasTolentino maybe you need to modify your vscode settings, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77314336/always-use-alias-for-automatic-imports