# Always use alias for automatic imports

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, import

Is there a way to force autoimport to **always** use the alias for importing modules in a NextJS@13.x project using VSCode?

I would like to use them even when it's a sibling component, no exceptions, so instead of

```js
import { Navbar } from "./components";
```

I would like to **force** auto-import to use the alias in **all cases**:

```js
import { Navbar } from "@/components";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have your `tsconfig.json` (or `jsconfig.json`) setup for path aliases correctly, you can change VSCode's preferences in your User Settings. Search for "Import Module Specifier" and you should see two entries - one for TypeScript and one for JavaScript. To always use the path alias, change these to `non-relative`.

[image: settings to change in vscode]

If you prefer editing your `settings.json` directly, the keys are:

```
{
  //...
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative",
  "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative",
  //...
}
```

If you want to do this at a per-project level, instead change these for your Workspace Settings.

Answer (score -3):

The purpose of **alias** is to simplify import of your functions/classes/etc.

Instead of typing:

```
import { Navbar } from "./../../../components";
```

You can create an alias to, for example, `components`:

```
import { Navbar } from "@/components";
```

The aliases are relied to your compiler options - jsconfig.json (tsconfig.json).

Here is example of `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      // Add more aliases as needed
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more info [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/absolute-imports-and-module-aliases)

Comment: I'm aware of what aliases are for. I just want to force auto-import to always use aliases.
It sometimes uses relative paths when auto-importing.

Comment: Probably I didn't understand your comment correctly. You like to use only aliases, but this is your "developer side". Your environment, once you set the aliases will propose to use it as auto-import (for example, VSCode).
Nextjs and JS don't care about your imports, finally before JS executes the code all "paths" will be absolute, aliases are designed for "human purposes"