# How do I set up and use aliases in a Vite React JS project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, alias, mern

I'm working on a React JS project with Vite as the bundler, and I want to improve my project's module import paths using aliases. Could someone provide a step-by-step guide on how to set up and use aliases in a Vite project?

I have already added the following configuration to my package.json and vite.config.js:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mern-wp-lms",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 5",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // existing dependencies
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // existing devDependencies
  },
  "vite": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

**vite.config.js:**

```
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

const __filename = import.meta.url;
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ["js-big-decimal"],
  },
  server: {
    port: 8000,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: { "components": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/components") },
  },
});
```

However, when I try to import a component using the alias in my code, it doesn't seem to work as expected. For example:

`` `import Header from "components/Header";` ``

What am I missing, and how can I correctly set up and use aliases in my Vite React project? had tried all the possible methods and options available on the web. Such as :

[How to set multiple aliases in vite react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75201705/how-to-set-multiple-aliases-in-vite-react)

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/setting-up-aliases-vite-react-typescript-aurelian-spodarec-/

https://dev.to/avxkim/setup-path-aliases-w-react-vite-ts-poa

[How to set multiple aliases in vite react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75201705/how-to-set-multiple-aliases-in-vite-react)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are some adjustments needed in both the **package.json** and **vite.config.js** to properly set up and use aliases in your Vite React project.

**package.json**

```
  "baseUrl": "./src",
  "paths": {
    "@assets/*": [
      "assets/* "
    ],
    "@components/*": [
      "components/*"
    ],
    "@features/*": [
      "features/*"
    ],
    "@pages/*": [
      "pages/*"
    ],
    "@theme/*": [
      "@theme/*"
    ],
    "@utils/*": [
      "@utils/*"
    ]
  }
```

**vite.config.js**

```
 resolve: {
    alias: {
      assets:"/src/assets",
      components: "/src/components",
      mockData:"/src/data",
      features:"/src/features",
      pages: "/src/pages",
      theme: "/src/theme",
      utils: "/src/utils",
    },
  },
```

And import as `import Header from "components/Header";`